# How to use multiple AngularJS directives on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jquery directives in angular project
1. Datepicker
2. JScrollpane
but when I use multiple times it modified the same object e.g.
in case of date picker when I choose date from one date picker it automatically changes in another one similar for Jscrollpane it takes height of 1st one

```
iqApp.directive('jquerydatepicker', [  function() {
       return function(scope, element, attrs) {
           element.datepicker({
               inline: true,
               dateFormat: scope.format,

               changeMonth: true,
               changeYear: true,
               showOn: 'button',
               buttonImageOnly: true
           });
       }
} ]);

 iqApp.directive('jscrollpane', [ function() {
    function link(scope, element, attr) {

        var $window = $(window);
        var $element = $(element), api;

        $element.jScrollPane();
        api = $element.data('jsp');

        $window.on("touchstart mousemove resize",  function onLoad() {
            var _finalHeight = $window.height() - $element.offset().top;
            $('.jspContainer').height(_finalHeight);
            api.reinitialise();
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : link
    };
} ]);
```

Comment: `Scope : True` ( Directive gets a new scope ) http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the directives are the issues here, rather the issue is which variable holds the value for the `date picker` for example. If you have two date pickers and their values are both stored in an arbitrary variable `$scope.date` then when one changes, the other will change as well courtesy of **two-way data binding**, so you might want to double-check your HTML or you could edit your question and include that as well

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by making some changes to the fixed element based height:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    iqApp.directive('jscrollpane', [ '$timeout', function($timeout) {
        function link(scope, element, attr) {

            var $window = $(window);
            var $element = $(element), api;

            $element.jScrollPane();
            api = $element.data('jsp');

            $window.on("resize mousemove touchstart", function onLoad() {

                var _finalHeight = $window.height() - $element.offset().top;
                $(element).find('.jspContainer').height(_finalHeight);
                api.reinitialise();
            });

            var timeout = $timeout(function() {
                //console.log('dr load timer');
                var _finalHeight = $window.height() - $element.offset().top;
                $(element).find('.jspContainer').height(_finalHeight);
                api.reinitialise();
            }, 1000);
        }

        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            link : link
        };
    } ]);
})();
```